# Where do I handle form validation errors returned by the server in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, form-submit

I'm using React 16.12.0.  I'm trying to figure out how to handle and display validation errors that are returned from my server.  I have this form set up ...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';

/* Import Components */
import Input from '../components/Input';
import Country from '../components/Country';
import Province from '../components/Province';
import Button from '../components/Button'

class FormContainer extends Component {
  statics: {
    DEFAULT_COUNTRY: 484;
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      countries: [],
      provinces: [],
      newCoop: {
        name: '',
        type: {
          name: ''
        },
        address: {
          formatted: '',
          locality: {
            name: '',
            postal_code: '',
            state: ''
          },
          country: 484, //FormContainer.DEFAULT_COUNTRY,
        },
        enabled: true,
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        web_site: ''
      },

    }
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }

  /* This life cycle hook gets executed when the component mounts */

  handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const NC = this.state.newCoop;
    delete NC.address.country;

    fetch('/coops/',{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newCoop),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      }).then(response => {
        response.json().then(data =>{
          console.log("Successful" + data);
        })
    })
  }
  handleClearForm() {
    // Logic for resetting the form
  }
  handleInput(e) {
    let self=this
    let value = e.target.value;
    console.log("value:" + value);
    let name = e.target.name;
    //update State
    this.setValue(self.state.newCoop,name,value)
  }

  setValue = (obj,is, value) => {
       if (typeof is == 'string')
         return this.setValue(obj,is.split('.'), value);
       else if (is.length === 1 && value!==undefined)
         return this.setState({obj: obj[is[0]] = value});
       else if (is.length === 0)
         return obj;
       else
         return this.setValue(obj[is[0]],is.slice(1), value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <form className="container-fluid" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
            <FormGroup
 controlId="formBasicText">

                <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Name'}
                   name= {'name'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.name}
                   placeholder = {'Enter cooperative name'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}

                   /> {/* Name of the cooperative */}

                <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Type'}
                   name= {'type.name'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.type.name}
                   placeholder = {'Enter cooperative type'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}

                   /> {/* Type of the cooperative */}

                <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Street'}
                   name= {'address.formatted'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.address.formatted}
                   placeholder = {'Enter address street'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}

                   /> {/* Address street of the cooperative */}

                <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'City'}
                   name= {'address.locality.name'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.address.locality.name}
                   placeholder = {'Enter address city'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}

                   /> {/* Address city of the cooperative */}

              <Country title={'Country'}
                  name={'address.country'}
                  options = {this.state.countries}
                  value = {this.state.newCoop.address.country}
                  placeholder = {'Select Country'}
                  handleChange = {this.handleInput}
                  /> {/* Country Selection */}

              <Province title={'State'}
                  name={'address.locality.state'}
                  options = {this.state.provinces}
                  value = {this.state.newCoop.address.locality.state}
                  placeholder = {'Select State'}
                  handleChange = {this.handleInput}
                  /> {/* State Selection */}

              <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Postal Code'}
                   name= {'address.locality.postal_code'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.address.locality.postal_code}
                   placeholder = {'Enter postal code'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}

                   /> {/* Address postal code of the cooperative */}

              <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Email'}
                   name= {'email'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.email}
                   placeholder = {'Enter email'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}

                   /> {/* Email of the cooperative */}

              <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Phone'}
                   name= {'phone'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.phone}
                   placeholder = {'Enter phone number'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}

                   /> {/* Phone number of the cooperative */}

              <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Web Site'}
                   name= {'web_site'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.web_site}
                   placeholder = {'Enter web site'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}

                   /> {/* Web site of the cooperative */}


              <Button
                  action = {this.handleFormSubmit}
                  type = {'primary'}
                  title = {'Submit'}
                  style={buttonStyle}
              /> { /*Submit */ }

              <Button
                  action = {this.handleClearForm}
                  type = {'secondary'}
                  title = {'Clear'}
                  style={buttonStyle}
              /> {/* Clear the form */}

            </FormGroup>
        </form>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let initialCountries = [];
    let initialProvinces = [];
    // Get initial countries
    fetch('/countries/')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
        initialCountries = data.map((country) => {
            return country
        });
        console.log("output ...");
        console.log(initialCountries);
        this.setState({
            countries: initialCountries,
        });
    });
    // Get initial provinces (states)
    fetch('/states/484/')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        initialProvinces = data.map((province) => {
            return province
        });
        this.setState({
            provinces: initialProvinces,
        });
    });
  }
}

const buttonStyle = {
  margin : '10px 10px 10px 10px'
}

export default FormContainer;
```

When the server (a Django Python app) isn't able to process the form, it returns a 400 with a response body with errors linked to each field.  For example, such a response body would look like

```
{"phone":["The phone number entered is not valid."]}
```

What is the proper way to catch this error and display it in my form?  All the examples I've seen deal with validation BEFORE the form is submitted -- e.g. writing an "validateFields" method, or something similar in the "handleFormSubmit" handler before it ends.

**Edit:** Added new fetch method in response to comments.  Adding the "catch" block is not displaying the error when the fetch request is returning 400 though.

```
fetch('/coops/',{
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newCoop),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
}).then(response => {
    response.json().then(data =>{
        console.log("Successful" + data);
    })
}).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

The CHrome dev console reports a 400 on the request as well as

```
FormContainer.jsx:54 Fetch failed loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/coops/".
```

Additionally the "Success" console.log message prints out despite the 400 and what Chrome reports.

Comment: Well, there is form field validation, which occurs *before* a form is submitted, but it sounds like you're asking about displaying form processing errors. Presumably these errors would come back as a Promise rejection from the `fetch`. Can you confirm where in your code you receive the errors. From there they can displayed pretty much any way you want. What is your expected error UI? (a list of errors above the form? some holder error text below each field? etc...) Can you update your question with these details?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I guess that's my quesiton -- where in my code am I supposed to be catching errors returned from my form submit and displaying them?  I assume it's in the handleFormSubmit function I have, but I'm not entirely clear.  Also not sure if the structure that my error is being returned in is the best for react, so I'm open to exploring changing that as well.

Comment: Add a `.catch(error => console.log(error));` block to the promise chain returned by `fetch` and try submitting form data you know should fail and return error. If my intuition is correct you should see them logged in the catch block. If the returned errors have a good way to relate them back to form fields that pretty much any shape will work; what you have seems sufficient. Once we confirm where you receive your errors back we can figure out how to display them.

Comment: Thanks for your continued assistance.  I editred to my question to show where I put the "catch" block, although it doesn't get invoked.  Although I can see in the console a 400 returned from the server, the console.log success message continues to print out.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, seems `fetch` won't [reject on http error status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Differences_from_jQuery). You will in fact get them in the "resolved" branch but need to check `response.ok` (200-299), anything else will likely have the error status you need, maybe `response.statusText`, but this depends entirely on how your server packs it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling form submission error response.

```
fetch('/coops/',{
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newCoop),
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
}).then(response => {
  // check if received an OK response, throw error if not
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  throw new Error(response.statusText);        
}).then(jsonData => {
  console.log("Successful", jsonData);
}).catch(errors => {
  // If error was thrown then unpack here and handle in component/app state
  console.log('error', errors);
  this.setState({ errors });
});
```

Display a simple list of errors (assumes all errors are shape `{[string]: arrayOf(string)}`)

```
render() {
  const errors = Object.values(this.state.errors);
  return (
    <form
      className="container-fluid"
      onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
    >
      <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText">

        {errors.length && (
          <ul>
            {errors.map(error => <li>{error.join(" ")}</li>}
          </ul>
        )}

        <Input
          inputType={'text'}
          title= {'Name'}
          name= {'name'}
          value={this.state.newCoop.name}
          placeholder = {'Enter cooperative name'}
          handleChange = {this.handleInput}
        /> {/* Name of the cooperative */}
        ...
```

Display field level errors

```
render() {
  const { errors } = this.state;
  return (
    <form
      className="container-fluid"
      onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
    >
      <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText">

        <Input
          inputType={'text'}
          title= {'Name'}
          name= {'name'}
          value={this.state.newCoop.name}
          placeholder = {'Enter cooperative name'}
          handleChange = {this.handleInput}
        /> {/* Name of the cooperative */}
        {errors.name && (
          <div className="fieldError">
            {error.name.join(" ")}
          </div>
        )}

        <Input
          inputType={'text'}
          title= {'Type'}
          name= {'type.name'}
          value={this.state.newCoop.type.name}
          placeholder = {'Enter cooperative type'}
          handleChange = {this.handleInput}
        /> {/* Type of the cooperative */}
        {errors.name && (
          <div className="fieldError">
            {error['type.name"].join(" ")}
          </div>
        )}
        ...
```

The latter is such a common pattern that many form libraries take the form errors as a prop directly and handle displaying an error helper text themselves. Many handle a form of both, with a reserved form level error key, i.e. `_error`, and then all the field level errors, which use the field name as their key.

Comment: Cool, so this successfully handles the error.  So the other part of my question was does react have any standard ways of tying the various errors back to the fields to which they pertain so that it's easy to display those fields?

Comment: @Dave react, itself, doesn't have a standard way, but there are quite a few form frameworks/libraries out there to handle this, each depending on your needs. Two common ways of displaying form submission errors is to, one, simply display a list of errors at the top of the page/form and focus on them when rendered, or two, render some helper error text with each field with the error belonging to that field. I'll try to update my answer.